# Unable to reboot my newly built PC

Tags: windows-7, computer-building

I built a new PC but I realized from even before installing Windows 7 that my PC does not reboot pushing the "reset" button on the case. I managed to install an OS by hard booting it. Now this PC is able to shut down from OS but still unable to reboot. Is this a hardware (case) issue or possibly a motherboard issue?  I checked all the wiring and + and -, and all are wired correctly. If it's a motherboard issue (which is most unlikely), how can I check it?  If this is a case defect, does the case's reset button have to be functional in order to reboot even from Windows?

Comment: "Reset" button is directly wired to the motherboard, it will work in any state of the computer unless it's powered off, so OS doesn't matter.

Comment: If you had a multimeter with a resistance-measuring range, or even just a continuity checker, then you could easily check that the case reset button is working. Could it be that some part of the case is misaligned slightly and preventing the reset button from being pressed far enough?

Comment: Thank you all for quick responses.  I troubleshoot every possible issues I could think of and came to two conclusions:  both reset wire on the case and motherboard are defect.  What is your opinion on this?  I maybe asking a question you might have already answered, Little Helper, but I need to reconfirm.  Can computer be reboot even "reset" function not working on the case?  If so, the motherboard is the sole issue.  I appreciate for your help!

Comment: @Rick You should not use the reset switch to reboot when you have an OS running. That is likely to cause corruption on the disk drive(s) because the OS will not have a chance to make sure it has written everything it needs to to the drive(s).

Answer (score 2):

About your last line 
**"does case's reset button have to be functioned in order to reboot even from Windows?"**
N.B:-
 - the button has nothing to do with your OS's restart option.
 - If you have installed the OS successfully then you can definitely restart it from there(OS)

Answer:-
From your current situation I can say that it is pretty much a hardware fault, so recheck your connections and replace the button if needed